# How to re-use elements in a ejb-jar.xml deployment descriptor?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, ejb-3.0, ejb-3.1

I'm currently writing a set of EJBs that interface with some old EJB2 code. As part of this, I have an `ejb-jar.xml` deployment descriptor that contains resource-refs and ejb-refs for the session beans. All of these definitions are basically identical - only the session bean's name differs between them. Obviously, this isn't ideal - every time I add a new bean, I have to copy and paste a large block of XML.

The structure looks something like this:

```
<ejb-jar 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_1.xsd" version="3.1">
    <enterprise-beans>
        <session>
            <ejb-name>/* redacted */</ejb-name>

            <resource-ref>
                <res-ref-name>/* redacted */</res-ref-name>
                <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
                <res-auth>Application</res-auth>
                <lookup-name>/* redacted */</lookup-name>
            </resource-ref>

            <ejb-ref>
                <ejb-ref-name>/* redacted */</ejb-ref-name>
                <ejb-ref-type>Session</ejb-ref-type>
                <home>/* redacted */</home>
                <remote>/* redacted */</remote>
            </ejb-ref>

            /* about 20 more ejb-refs later... */
        </session>

        /* several near identical session beans here ... */
</ejb-jar>
```

Is there any way to re-use these references in multiple definitions without duplication? Or, alternatively, is there a better way of achieving the same end result that I'm missing?

Comment: Is this websphere, if so what version? Prior to websphere 7 (and unless patched even 7) there is no solution for this, as these come with Java EE 5. JEE6 does have global resource references, you might have to check the documentation corresponding to your particular product. Also if you are using appropriate version of RAD, it might automatically take care of this.

Comment: @Gautam: WebSphere 8/JEE 6, thankfully - our app is legacy, but it's not *that* legacy :p Slightly complicated by us having to support JBoss 7 as well, though. I'll look into global resource refs, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: You may want to start looking here [JEE namespaces](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS7JFU_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.express.doc/ae/cejb_bindingsejbfp.html#cejbbindingsejbfp__javaGlobalNamespaces).

Comment: Does each session bean actually use all of those ejb-refs? Each one is intended to be for an individual "java:comp/env/..." JNDI lookup from within the calling scope of each bean. It looks like you might be using the same big fat "Locator" service for everything...

Comment: @SteveC: Probably not all of them - I'm migrating an application that used to route everything through one EJB to have multiple EJB/JAX-WS endpoints, so that's the full list of all the EJBs in the app - could probably narrow it down...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my particular scenario, I was able to solve the issue by packaging the EJBs as a WAR instead of a plain JAR file - this allowed me to provide the references in `web.xml` for the application as a whole, rather than on a per-bean level.